# White outline on PNGs but only when zoomed out

Tags: png

Here is my site:
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/pp/

The 'Shop by Category' menu on the left is made of images and uses PNGs. The PNGs look fine at normal zoom but when I zoom out in FF and also on my Ipad white lines appear where the transparency begins.

I know PNGs can cause lots of headaches cross browser but this seems like a different issue. I havn't tested with other browsers.

Thanks

UPDATE - Does anyone know a link to a site where a PNG with transparency is shown over a background image or color? I want to see if this issue happens to other people in case its impossible to fix.

UPDATE2- I think this only happens on ipad and mac, but not pc.

UPDATE 3 - Here is a screen grab from firefox mac when Im zoomed out:

[image]

Comment: I cant see it happening with FF on my PC but its hard to say for sure its subtle anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your PNGs actually contain white.

Take a look at your PNG with its alpha channel removed [image: your PNG with alpha removed]

and compare it to this modified version with the alpha channel removed [image: modified version with the alpha channel removed]

Here is the modified version with alpha channel intact: [image: modified version with alpha channel intact] - it looks the same as your file, but the transparent pixels are grey and transparent, not white and transparent. Try this version on your site and it should work.

To help you further, we'll need to know what software you are using to save the images. For example, in GIMP you have to make sure that you select "Save background color" when exporting the PNG, but other software may work differently.

Comment: Using your image doesn't seem to fix the problem. Im using photoshop, ive set the background to a color other than white and when I zoom in I cant see any white. I also cant see any semi-transparent pixels, their either see through or not. I think their PNG8 which doenst have semi transparency. Thanks